# SharePoint/Outlook 2007, forwarding Designer e-mail links

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, outlook

I'm using SharePoint, Outlook and Designer 2007.

I'm using a Designer workflow to notify the assigned person when a list item is updated. The e-mail Designer sends contains a link to the list item built as follows...

```
To view the request, click <a href="http://SITEURL.com/Lists/LISTNAME/DispForm.aspx?ID=IDLOOKUP">here</a>
```

This link works fine for the user it is sent to but if this email is forwarded then Outlook somehow adds "%0d%0a" to the end e.g. http://SITEURL.com/Lists/LISTNAME/DispForm.aspx?ID=5%0d%0a

It you follow the link you view a blank list item which says things like "Name: Name field value, Date: Date field value" etc

When forwarding the link to someone with Outlook 2010 this does not occur.

Is there a setting I need to change or does this always happen with 2007?

Comment: I am having similar problem but not just in forwarding. Multiple people receive the same email that has the href syntax. When the link is produced it will show gxx-portal/corporate/Lists/Terminated/EditForm.aspx?ID=31" this will produce a strange form as indicated above with the default values. The link that works is gxx-portal/corporate/Lists/Terminated/EditForm.aspx?ID=31 It does not have the " at the end of 31. Have you had any success in resolving? If so will you share? Mine is similar
FWM

Comment: Please make this a comment to the original question. You accidentally entered a comment as an answer. [moderator: I have converted it to a comment on his behalf]

Comment: I've never had a " at the end of a link. How are you generating the links?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting alerts on the AssignedToMe view instead of a workflow?  You may be able to forward a Sharepoint formatted alert better.

Comment: I didn't find these alerts accurate enough i.e. they wouldn't fire every time and if the assigned person changes  the user would get an alert when the assigned field changes from them to someone else. Also by controlling the emails through Designer, I don't have to set up alerts everytime a new user is added to the site. Thanks for the suggestion though :)